# What does "Impression Change" in Google webmaster->search mean?

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, impressions

I have been using Google Webmaster Tools. I checked out the search queries section. There I found a lot keywords and its report, but I could not understand what the data in those reports mean. Can anyone help me with a reference or meaning of "impression", "change", and "other"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Impression**: how many times your site was viewed by a user in the search results

**Change**: the change, either positive or negative, in the value since the last rolling 30 day period. Positive is better.

**Clicks**: How many people clicked on your website in the search results for that term

**CTR**: stands for click through rate. It means what percentage of people who saw your listing actually clicked on your link. Higher is better.

**Avg Position**: the average ranking for your pages for that search term.

Read: [Understanding the data](https://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=96568&hl=en)